# MQTT callback handling

Tags: c, arduino, mqtt, iot

I am trying to convert a byte* parameter passed into an mqtt callback function to an int for comparison and I can't seem to get it working. Any help would be welcomed.

```
int fsrReading;
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {

  for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {

    Serial.print((char)payload[i]); // This works well

    fsrReading = int((char)payload[i]); 

    if (fsrReading < 0){
       ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this depends on exactly what representation of a number is being used.

I suspect the message is a string representation of a number: "1234", which is being received as an array of ascii byte values.

If that is the case, you can rebuild a String object and convert it to an int:

```
int fsrReading;
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  String value = "";
  for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
      value += (char)payload[i];
  }
  fsrReading = value.toInt();
  ...
```

There is an example of converting a String to an Int in the arduino tutorials here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringToIntExample

Comment: One more "the best non standard C++ string implementation" ? In my opinion this is one of sources defeat of C++ language.... I don't know that arduino developers made such invention. Sorry for sarcasm.

Comment: I use Your understanding of representation in my answer (what is not clear in question, and author don't send full explanation). Can You forgive me? ;) Sarcasm is not for You, because of to general strange evolution of C++ libraries.

Comment: Thank you this really helped

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: original answer part before explanation:*

Depends on compiler, compiler  options etc `char` can be `signed` or `unsigned`, cast via `(char)` can work different than You expect.

Example:

payload[i] is 0x81

unsigned char -> 129, then >0

signed char -> -127, then <0

Your cast via (char) is redundant (and unstable like i said)

I don't give sample code because I don't understand Your goal. Code has contradictions.

Disclaimer: Your `byte` seems non standard type. I **belive** that is `unsigned char` a such type NEVER is <0 .

What is main sense of this variable? In deep, it is signed or unsigned? You can cast `(unigned char)` but is never<0 or `(signed char)` - up to You

EDIT:
after comment of asker, and interpretation from knolleary hot to interpret length (important: change of loop sense, maybe you understand author correctly) I give pure C conversion

```
 int val = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
      val = val*10 + payload[i]-'0';
  }
// If someone know end of number is marked in different way, need implement break of `for`
  fsrReading =val;
```

I believe my is few CPU cycles/RAM better.

**EDIT2:** I have read few materials from Arduino community, problem with loop concatenation into String is like in many languages: many, many small allocations (while concatenation is totally not required here). Many good Arduino programmers are critical to overuse of `String`. It isn't "secret knowledge", it is general rule in programming.

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=185469.0

http://www.gammon.com.au/concat

Comment: My goal is to convert the byte array into a int fsrReading. I was thinking of using the for loop to capture each byte array element and then assigning it to a char array. In essence I am trying to get the string representation of the passed in byte array so I can do a comparison on the int value.

Comment: Casting a byte to a char will not give you a numerical string

Comment: Agree with hardillb. How long is such numeric sequence? Terminated by `'\0'`, separator, any by non-digit character etc? But You (user1907509) print ONLY ONE byte/character. Thats why code is hard to understand